# I have saved coordinates in firebase real time database? How to retrieve the coordinates in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As I have saved coordinates in firebase real time database of all the authenticated user. Now I want to retrieve  all  the coordinates which is on firebase database to show on map 
like multiple marker on single map

Here is my code for sending location to firebase

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            FirebaseUser user = fb.getCurrentUser();
            databaseReference.child("Location").child(user.getUid()).child("parth1234").setValue(location.getLatitude() + " , " + location.getLongitude());
        }
```

Now how can I retrieve these location into map activity 
as  have created map activity, but I don't know anything related to this 
please help with some code

Thanks in advance

I am beginner in android studio

is the saving location into firebase method  which i have used is correct method ??

Answer (score 0):

You are setting in correct way.
To retrieve data you need to attach a Value Listener(for more info https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write
Do the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Location").child((user.getUid()).child("parth1234").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     //Now you can do whatever you want with that location value
     //dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)
     //I printed it in the code below for you
     System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     //Handle the error
}
});
```

Comment: i dont think so   System.out.println(postSnapshot.getValue(String.class)); is going work in android

Comment: how can i use system.out.println in android

Comment: It will work you can see the value in the Android Studio

Comment: i want to retrieve all the location on map with markers ? how this code will work?

Comment: System.out.println(postSnapshot.getValue(String.class)); why you have used postSnapshot . error is coming

Comment: My bad! Please change it to dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)

Comment: that i did.but still a map is displayed but no marker and no location.

Comment: For the map part please do check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker It is quite complicate I cannot just tell it here so you better check documentation